# Error con el variable global $_POST en PHP no me retorna el dato solicitado me dice que no esta definida

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buenas estoy teniendo problemas al tratar de obtener un dato con el método post este me arroja un error de (Warning: Undefined array key "vendedor") pero creo que esta correcto no se por que del error ya cambie el nombre de la variable, ya le puse la misma que tiene en la base de datos en fin no encuentro el error alguien sabe el por que pasa eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les anexo el código para ver si buscan el error donde fallo:

```
<?php

    require '../../includes/config/database.php';
    $db = conectarDB();

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === 'POST') {
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";

        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
        $precio = $_POST['precio'];
        $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
        $habitaciones = $_POST['habitaciones'];
        $wc = $_POST['wc'];
        $estacionamiento = $_POST['estacionamiento'];
        $vendedor = $_POST['vendedor'];
    }


    require '../../includes/funciones.php';
    incluirTemplate('header');
        
?>

    <main class="contenedor seccion">

        <h1>Crear</h1>

        <a href="/admin/index.php" class="boton boton-verde">Volver</a>

        <form action="/admin/propiedades/crear.php" method="POST" class="formulario">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Informacion General</legend>

            <label for="titulo">Titulo</label>
            <input name="titulo" type="text" id="titulo" placeholder="Titulo Propiedad">

            <label for="precio">Precio</label>
            <input name="precio" type="number" id="precio" placeholder="Precio Propiedad">

            <label for="imagen">Imagen</label>
            <input type="file" id="imagen" accept="image/jpeg, image/png">

            <label for="descripcion">Descripcion</label>
            <textarea name="descripcion" id="descripcion"></textarea>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Información de la Propiedad</legend>

            <label for="habitaciones">Habitaciones</label>
            <input name="habitaciones" type="number" id="habitaciones" placeholder="Ej: 2" min="1" max="9">

            <label for="wc">Baños</label>
            <input name="wc" type="number" id="wc" placeholder="Ej: 2" min="1" max="9">

            <label for="estacionamiento">Estacionamiento</label>
            <input name="estacionamiento" type="number" id="estacionamiento" placeholder="Ej: 2" min="1" max="3">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Vendedor</legend>

            <select name="vendedor">
                <option value="" disabled selected>-- Selecciona a un Vendedor --</option>
                <option value="1">Edgardo</option>
                <option value="2">Eduardo</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Crear Propiedad" class="boton boton-amarillo">

        </form>

    </main>

    <?php

    incluirTemplate('footer');
        
?>
```

En la Mysql tengo definido como llave foranea vendedorId y una tabla que se llama vendedor

Comment: Y que es lo que muestra `var_dump($_POST);`?

Answer (score 3):

Prueba quitando el "disabled selected" del primer option del select.
Al estar como disabled, no se envia en el POST y por lo tanto no aparece en el array.

Como supongo que el `disabled` lo estas poniendo para intentar que no se mande el formulario sin seleccionar una de las otras dos opciones, puedes poner `required` al `select`, y puesto que el value del primer `option` es `""`, no dejara enviar el formualario si no se ha seleccionado ninguna de las otras dos.

Comment: Es una opción aunque insegura ya que eso se puede modificar si habrás la consola de desarrollado, es recomendable hacer alguna otra validación,  ya se en el frontend con javascript o en le backend con php

Comment: Gracias ahora lo checo

Comment: hay alguna manera de dejar el opción que diga selecciona a un vendedor pero que tena la opción de disable para que no se pueda seleccionar y a la vez poder cumplir con la función de post?

Comment: Puedes explicar ( para ver si conseguimos ayudarte ) porque quieres marcar ( con selected ) un vendendor, pero que a su vez ese vendedor no pueda ser seleccionado? No tiene mucho sentido querer seleccionar algo pero a la vez hacerlo no seleccionable...
A parte, de que como comenta @christian, todo eso puede ser modificado desde el inspector de elementos, por lo cual recuerda siempre validar los datos una vez hayan sido enviados por el usuario.